# Can Azure Synapse query AVRO? (EventHubs capture files)

Tags: avro, azure-synapse, polybase, azure-data-lake-gen2

## Question

Hive has built-in support for AVRO.  Using Azure Synapse (aka hosted version of PolyBase) can I use Hive's built-in AVRO SerDe to query data in ADL Gen2 storage?

### Scenario

I work at a financial firm that has a lot of data in [FIX-trading format](https://www.fixtrading.org/update-of-online-spec/).  I am building a spike to try to query the raw FIX data out of FIX files (historical, years of data) and FIX messages forwarded via Azure Event Hubs (AEH, which I believe will be captured to ADL Gen2 in AVRO format, one AVRO row per FIX trading message).  I'm starting with the historical files that are "just FIX".

### Ominus Quote

From [Synapse **External Table** documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#limitations-and-restrictions):

> The combinations of supported SerDe methods with RCFiles, and the supported data compression methods are listed previously in this article. Not all combinations are supported.

Comment: My boss mentioned Synapse DOES support ORC and Parquet.  I'm afraid those file formats might not be good for FIX-trading data because FIX message streams contain a combination of small commands and very wide messages: order data, fills aka execution data.  When FIX files are converted to, say, CSV they are huge because they are sparse.  I'd like to parse FIX directly or use a format designed for sparse data.  ORC might be good if partitioned correctly (by message type), but we're trying to answer these questions first.

Answer (score 0):

My team found an [older post on how to query FIX data using Hive and Impala](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/sql-on-hadoop-hive-part-i), and I'm trying to figure out how to apply that to Azure Synapse or Azure Notebooks.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE fix_map
 (tag MAP< INT, STRING>)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED COLLECTION ITEMS
 TERMINATED BY ‘1’
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘2’
 MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY ‘=’
 LOCATION ‘/user/jeremy/fix/’;
```

```
CREATE VIEW fix_view AS
    tag[38] AS OrderQty
  , tag[55] AS Symbol
  , tag[60] AS TransactTime
    fix_map;
    OrderQty
  , Symbol
  , TransactTime
FROM fix_view;
```

```
SELECT
    OrderQty
  , `Symbol`
  , TransactTime
FROM fix;
```